# Google Spreadsheet substract or add to row/column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i have a spreadsheet with our warehouse.
There is the Name of the item and the current stock.

Now i will have a field, when i type in `5` than the stock must add +5 on the stock and the `5` will be deleted out of the field so i can type in the next one.

Is that possible to have a field in Column `A` so its adding from column `A1`on top of the stock on `D1`or something and than is deleting the number automatically that i typed it?

I dont want that the number is forever in there (like the 5 that added to stock). It just calculate the new stock up and than deleting the `5` out of the field

So just a field that looks like empty but with a function behind who add the number to the stock in Column `D`

I know that i can =SUM numbers together or something but i dont want to hold the added number in the old field, it must be deleted but after its calculated to the new stock

Comment: It sounds possible but I would require a few examples from you describing exactly what you want.  You may think that you've already done that but I would appreciate some images to make it more clear exactly what you have when you start and exactly what the outcome is when the process you're requesting ends.

Answer (score 0):

So you want a column where you can enter a number that will mutate your stock.

Here's what I've come up with.

## Sheet layout

I've currently set it up that you have 4 columns, item, code, stock and the mutate column. All you need to do is enter a value in the D column and it'll be added to the C column's stock.

[image]

Column D is used for your input. Here's a little example:

[image]

## Code

Make sure to change the sheetname variable to whatever your sheet is called.

```js
function warehouseStock(e) {
  const sheetName = 'enter your own sheet name here';
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  if (e.range.getColumn() != 4) {
    return;
  }

  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const incrementNumber = e.range.getValue();
  const oldNumber = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();

  sheet.getRange(row, 3).setValue(oldNumber + incrementNumber);
  e.range.setValue('');

  }
```

## Trigger

Make sure to setup a trigger for this script to run every time you enter a value.

[image]